# Python print md5 file contents not working?

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
with open(path_to_wordlist) as f:
    for line in f:
        hashedword = hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()
        if hashedword == hashed_word:
            print('Your hash has been cracked! It is ' + str(line))
            sys.exit()
        print(hashedword)
        print('"' + line + '"')
    print('Your hash was not found in the wordlist.')
    sys.exit()
```

I have checked and confirmed that hashlib works when getting the md5 value of words, so I can't see why this won't work. It displays all hashes in the file, but it gets them all wrong. Here's my text file I'm working with.

```
123456
password
12345678
qwerty
123456789
```

123456 comes out as 'f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af', for example. Could somebody explain to me why this isn't working?

Here's the full output. Remember, those speech marks are not hashed, they're added afterwards as shown above.

```
f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af
"123456
"
286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4
"password
"
23cdc18507b52418db7740cbb5543e54
"12345678
"
a86850deb2742ec3cb41518e26aa2d89
"qwerty
"
b2cfa4183267af678ea06c7407d4d6d8
"123456789
"
```

I expected it to be

```
e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e
"123456
"
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
"password
"
25d55ad283aa400af464c76d713c07ad
"12345678
"
d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4
"qwerty
"
25f9e794323b453885f5181f1b624d0b
"123456789
"
```

Comment: How is it not working? looks fine to me.

Comment: why _what_ is not working?

Comment: Basically this returns each word on a new line of a file, as an md5 hash. It returns them all as hashes, but all the hashes are wrong

Comment: 'f447b20a7fcbf53a5d5be013ea0b15af' _is_ the hexdigest of the MD5 hash of `b'123456\n'`? In what sense is it wrong?

Comment: Edit my above post to show full output.

Comment: Please also show the output you expected to see. As far as I can tell, the output you've shown is correct.

Comment: password is shown differently to how it should be, this is how I found it should be https://duckduckgo.com/?q=password+md5&atb=v60-4_c&ia=answer

Comment: OTOH, `b'123456` hashes to 'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`. Note the absence of the newline character.

Comment: Your duckduckgo link shows the hash for `b'password'`, not the hash for `b'password\n'`.

Comment: Edited to show expected output

Comment: My program is supposed to hash the string without the newline, is that the problem? If so, how do I remove the new line?

Comment: The simple way to remove the newline is `line = line[:-1]`. There are other ways, eg you can strip off all trailing whitespace from a string, as mentioned in mkrieger1's answer, but you may not want to do that if the passwords can end in one or more spaces (or tabs).

Comment: Note that in Python 3 you can't pass text strings to the hashlib hash functions - you need to pass them bytes strings. So if you're reading from a text file (opened in text mode) you will need to encode your strings, eg with UTF-8 or Latin-1, before attempting to calculate their hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474270/python-print-md5-file-contents-not-working#comment74003826_43474270), it is relevant for the calculation of the MD5 hash whether the newline character (`\n`) at the end of each input line is considered part of the input or not.

> ```
> for line in f:
>     hashedword = hashlib.md5(line).hexdigest()
> ```

Here, `line` contains the entire line *including* the newline character.

You are apparently expecting to get the MD5 of the line contents *without* the newline character.

In order to implement this, you can for example pass `line.rstrip('\n')` instead of `line` to the `hashlib.md5` function.